# CSS Filter Chroma Does Not Work On IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, scrollbar

I have a iframe in may main page and I want to give trancparency for horizontal scrollbar in it. In chrome browser -webkit css styles working but I also need this in IE. I search it a lot and everyone says that using filter:chroma should work. I also read these examples [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532982(v=vs.85).aspx). In msdn example they said it should work IE 5.5 and later but I can't see the results working in IE 11. Also there is one people like me who comment on msdn page saying the filter:chroma is not working on IE 11.
So how can i filter specific color in IE 11 in CSS code or how can i give transparency to scrollbar?

This is code sample that I used for IE

```
body #myIframe {
/*IE 5.5. and later*/
scrollbar-track-color: #FF00FF;
scrollbar-face-color: #FF00FF;
scrollbar-highlight-color: #FF00FF;
scrollbar-3dlight-color: #FFFFFF;
scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #FF00FF;
scrollbar-shadow-color: #FFFFFF;
scrollbar-arrow-color: #FFFFFF;
filter: chroma(#FF00FF);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(color='#FF00FF');/*same as the above line*/
}
```

And this one is the code sample that is working on chrome browser.

```
/*chrome scrollbar style*/
::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many browsers ceased to support css changes on scrollbars.

You have a js solutions like this:
**[jscrollpane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com)**

Add this to your **Head tag**:

> ```
> <!-- styles needed by jScrollPane -->
> <link type="text/css" href="style/jquery.jscrollpane.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
>
> <!-- latest jQuery direct from google's CDN -->
> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
> </script>
>
> <!-- the mousewheel plugin - optional to provide mousewheel support -->
> <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
>
> <!-- the jScrollPane script -->
> <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
> ```

And this **jQuery** following to your container:

> `$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();`